# I get an Unexpected Output

Tags: c

In my book , this code is given.They say that the output is `2 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 6 5` 
Please explain is this correct or not ? If not then what is the correct o/p?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   int c[]={2,8,3,4,4,6,7,5};
   int j,*p=c,*q=c;
   for(j=0;j<5;j++){
       printf(" %d",*c);
       ++q;

   }
   for(j=0;j<5;j++){
       printf(" %d",*p);
       ++p;
   }
}
```

Comment: The output should be 2 2 2 2 2 2 8 3 4 4

Comment: I highly encourage you the use of a debugger to find runtime "error's" of this kind. This way you find not only the bug in most cases but also you learn a lot about programming itself.

Comment: http://ideone.com/sZ9LbK

Comment: if you want to learn, do debug yourself...It will give you the ability to visualize code execution.

Answer (score 1):

In first for-loop you are printing `*c` instead of `*q`:

```
printf(" %d",*c);  // outputs `2 2 2 2 2` as first element, five times
```

should be:

```
printf(" %d",*q);
```

as I notice you increments `q`

output is `2 2 2 2 2` in first loop because of `*c`, `c` decays into address of fist element in this expression.

**Edit**

According to your code output should be as suggested by @ChronoTrigge (I notice latter):

First loop outputs five times `2` as I explained above

second loop will output first five elements in array `a[]` so output should be:  `2 8 3 4 4`

complete output: `2 2 2 2 2 2 8 3 4 4`